# Ubuntu 11.10 Black Screen

Tags: usb, monitor, boot-failure, usb-drive

This is my current specs:

**Operating System:**   Windows 7 x64
**CPU:**            Intel Core i7 920  @ 2.67GHz Bloomfield 45nm Technology
**RAM:**            6.00 GB Tripple-Channel DDR3 @539MHz (8-8-8-20)
**Motherboard:**        Gigabyte Technology Co., EX58-EXTREME (Socket 1366)
**Graphics Card:**      nVidia GeForce GTS250 2048MB
**Monitor:**        LG Flatron W2443 (1920x1080@60Hz)

OK. Let's get started with the dirty bits.

I have created a persistent Ubuntu 11.10 x32 USB Pendrive Stick using Universal-USB-Installer v1.8.8.4 so I can try out the new features.

I get to the part when I reboot my PC with the USB pendrive on it and the Menu screen appears to choose what I want to do, so I choose option 1 to run via USB Pendrive option, but I get a black screen after choosing that option, well it actually turns off my monitor.

At the bottom of the screen where you should see the F6 key, or any other F keys, they are not there, all I see is the Ubuntu background at the bottom and when I try to hit the F6 key it just refreshes and nothing happens.

I had this problem once before but could not remember what I did to fix it in an older version of Ubuntu, I had to modify a .cfg file to be able to display the bottom part with the F keys. As I think it has something to do with the screen resolution, but not 100% sure.

I will try and burn a CD over the weekend and try and see what happens with the CD.

---

Thanks for your answers, but I have a problem with doing that request...

At the bottom of the screen where you should see the F6 key, or any other F keys, they are not there, all I see is the Ubuntu background at the bottom and when I try to hit the F6 key it just refreshes and nothing happens.

I had this problem once before but could not remember what I did to fix it in an older version of Ubuntu, I had to modify a .cfg file to be able to display the bottom part with the F keys.  As I think it has something to do with the screen resolution, but not 100% sure.

I will try and burn a CD over the weekend and try and see what happens with the CD.

NOTE: sorry I forgot my log in information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you scenario above above, but these are the common ways to fix the black screen issue.

> 1. If LiveCD  boots into a blank screen, when you see the boot menu hit F6 and select the “nomodeset” option.
> 2. If it boots into a blank screen after install.  Reboot and keep your finger on the “SHIFT” key till you get the grub menu. Highlight
>      the first entry and replace “quiet splash” with “nomodeset”.  Hit
>      CTRL + X to continue booting. Once logged in install the latest
>      Graphics drivers. System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers

source: http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/ubuntu-11-04-blank-screen-on-boot-solved/